# What face mask with glowing LEDs on the back is this health worker wearing?

Tags: face-mask-respirator

I saw a health worker in a short video clip wearing some kind of mask that loops around the back and has LEDs on it.

Does anyone know what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's some kind of compact PAPR in semi-mask form. Here's a [similar product](https://cleanspacetechnology.com/healthusa/)

[image]